# Making a UILabel disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am working on a kids app and need to make the answer disappear after a few seconds.
What do I need to add?

```
- (IBAction)calculate2:(id)sender
{     
    float aaaa = 6;     
    Answer2.text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f ",aaaa];      
}
```

Comment: well... at this point, i'd suggest utilizing an `NSTimer` object and doing `[labelObject setHidden:YES/NO];` at the appropriate times. Get this stuff in your code somewhere and if you're still having problems then edit this question with more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSTimer` and mention the specified time for `UILabel` to disappear:

```
- (IBAction)calculate2:(id)sender
{     
    float aaaa = 6;     
    Answer2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f ",aaaa];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}

-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    //toggle hidden parameter
    [Answer2 setHidden:!Answer2.hidden];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hussain, works great for disappearing, however when you depress it again, it will not reappear. Any idea why?

Comment: @ITforMobile : updated answer (_@HussainShabbir : i hope you didn't mind_)

Comment: Interesting result, Answer will reappear and then stay. When action depressed it will disappear with same delay. Thank you.

Comment: @Hussain Shabbir,do you know why it will not reappear when I depress the same action after it has disappeared?

Comment: You can check the condition, if it hidden is yes set it to no and if its no set to yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) hideLabel
{
      [Answer2 setHidden:YES];
}
```

just add `[self performSelector:@selector(hideLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:4]` to `calculate2`

Answer (score 0):

For hiding it non-animated it will be:

```
[label setHidden:YES];
```

But if you want to hide it with an Animation it could be:

```
[UIView animatedwithduration:1.0f delay:.35f animations:{

label.alpha = 0.0;


}completion:{
[label removeFromSuperview];
//Here you can put a completed code
}];
```

Hope it helps!